# Hole cover under bottom bracket: what is it and how do i screw it back in?

Tags: maintenance, repair, bottom-bracket

[image: hole cover]

So I got curios what is behind this cover and had a look. Turned the bike upside-down, unscrewed it and took it off. When trying to screw it back in, I realized that there is nowhere for the screw to go into. It kind of holds when I just push it back in, but doesn't leave me with confidence that it won't fall out on the road.

1. How do I re-attach it? Did I drop something inside that I need to get back out, if so how?
2. And what is it even for? I can't see the internal cable routing and I only found information about drain holes for water, but that should be the small one and shouldn't need a cover.
3. Is there a name for it? Did not have any luck with my google-fu.

Bike is a Cube Cross Race C:62 SL Teamline 2019 if that matters.

Comment: Turn the bike right-side up and shake it.  Does anything fall out, like a plastic hole for the screw to settle into ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Criggie! I tried that and it sounds like there is something, but haven't managed to shake it out.. Will try again later/after work.

Comment: It is a cover that is put in place after the internal cables are routed through the BB shell. You'll have to remove crank to get inside the shell to do the job. Brace yourself for a major job.

Comment: @Carel so once I remove the crank, I should be able to get inside and find "something" that the screw goes into?

Comment: @femot : Possibly, but there may still be a sleeve inside and more to do than just take the crank out, one of the bearings may have to be removed as well. Do you have the correct special tools for the the job and do you have the instructions to perform the re-assembly? (You may find videos on the subject on the internet.) If else, please rely on professional help.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to remove the bottom bracket to re-install that piece, even if you had the inner portion with you.

So just remove the bottom bracket and you'll see the backing portion that you're looking for and it'll be easy to see and install.

And to me it looks like some sort of cable guide used to hold your derailleur and brake cables/lines.